# Can I rollover a traditional IRA into a self-employed 401k if the self-employed business had no income this year?

Tags: united-states, 401k, rollover, solo-401k

I have a self-employed 401k, and I want to rollover a traditional IRA into it.  My self-employed business has no income this year, and I'm wondering if the rollover is allowed without tax penalties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limitations of money you earn only applies to contributions. Transfers, rollovers and conversions don't require income.  Gap years are great times to do conversions etc. that may have tax consequences.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Do you know of any resources where I can read more on this to help settle my concern? (Or can you give me more on your background?)

Comment: I would try Pub. 590 and https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/plan-participant-employee/rollovers-of-retirement-plan-and-ira-distributions ..... My credentials are I'm the only person who wrote an answer. Seriously, i did it after doing my own research and satisfying myself it was allowed, and the IRS didn't flag it...